# Error trying to switch image in jetpack compose

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I created a function and want to pass the activation after the condition to another function, but it gives me this error: `@Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a @Composable function`

Here is my code:

```
@Composable
fun RotatingImage() {
    val rotationState = rememberInfiniteTransition()
    val rotation by rotationState.animateFloat(
        initialValue = 0f,
        targetValue = 360f,
        animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
            animation = keyframes {
                durationMillis = 3000 },
            repeatMode = RepeatMode.Restart
        ), label = ""
    )

    val image: Painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.andew) // Замените на свой ресурс

    Image(
        painter = image,
        contentDescription = null, // Может быть null, если не нужно описание
        modifier = Modifier
            .size(100.dp) // Задайте размер изображения
            .rotate(rotation) // Примените вращение
    )
}

@Composable
fun Clickc() {
    var count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    Column {
        Text(text = count.value.toString(), color = Color.White)
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.watermelon),
            contentDescription = "im2",
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
                when (++count.value) {
                    10 -> RotatingImage() // <-- THERE'S THE PROBLEM
                }
            })
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You try to call RotatingImage() from within the onClick callback, but that callback is not inside the @Composable scope.

You need to separate this something like so:

```
Column {
    Text(text = count.value.toString(), color = Color.White)
    if (count < 10) {
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.watermelon),
            contentDescription = "im2",
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = { ++count.value })
        )
    } else {
        RotatingImage()
    }
}
```

Comment: The question was perfectly understandable for me (although I'm not speaking russian). Also it isn't off topic.

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget a Composable function must be quickly executed.  If you try and define a composable within the callback somehow state would have to be maintained, so the system would know whether or not it should be drawn.

The system has no way to reason this.  Therefor, instead of invoking the composable within the `onClick` method, save state there instead.

```
@Composable
fun Clickc() {
    var count = remember { mutableStateOf(0) }
    val (showRotateImage, setShowRotateImage) = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Column {
        Text(text = count.value.toString(), color = Color.White)
        Image(
            painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.watermelon),
            contentDescription = "im2",
            modifier = Modifier.clickable(onClick = {
                if (++count.value == 10) {
                    setShowRotateImage(true)
                }
            })
        )
        if(showRotateImage){
            RotatingImage()
        }
    }
}
```